# Constructing an f-string by for-looping through a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, f-string

I'd like to know how to go from this:

```
mylist = [10, 20, 30]
```

to this:

```
'Quantity 10, quantity 20 quantity 30'
```

I know it can be done with:

```
mystring = f"Quantity {mylist[0]}, quantity {mylist[1]} quantity {mylist[2]}"
```

but isn't there a way to incorporate a for-loop when constructing the f-string instead of having to provide all the list indexes one by one?

Edit: `Quantity`, `quantity`, and `quantity` just happen to be the same string, but they could be anything like     '`Quantity` 10, `rank` 20 `kingdom and sovrenity` 30'. So, there would be different text between the numbers.

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. You want something like `', '.join(f'quantity {i}' for i in mylist)`…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
", ".join([f"Quantity {x}" for x in mylist])
```

And if you care about the capitalisation....

```
f"Quantity {mylist[0]}, " + ", ".join([f"quantity {x}" for x in mylist[1:]])
```

EDIT: If the words are going to be different you need to zip them for the comprehension

```
words=["word1", "word2", "word3"]
numbers=[10,20,30]

', '.join([str(word) + " " + str(number) for word,number in zip(words,numbers)]).capitalize()
```

Comment: Seems like the `mylist[1:]` part should only be joined with `" "`

Comment: @tobias_k nope, run it yourself. My way gives exactly the same comma styling that was in the question

Comment: Nope, OP uses only one comma (like the capitalization this might also be a typo, though)

Comment: if capitalization counts, you'd better use `str.capitalize`: `", ".join([f"Quantity {x}" for x in mylist]).capitalize()`

Comment: @KJTHoward I don't think that would work. Please see the edit I made in my question.

Comment: @multigoodverse Would have been good to have that information at the start... But I've edited my answer which solves your edit