# Looping through 2 lists and inserting it in f string Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm looking for a way to insert 2 python lists in one f string.
I've already tried a number of solutions, including this one:[Constructing an f-string by for-looping through a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60603965/constructing-an-f-string-by-for-looping-through-a-list), but it can't seem to get it right.

I've already tried the '.join' method but I think I've made a mistake somewhere since it works for 1 list but not for two lists.

The goal is as follows:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',]

list2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'citrus', 'denim', 'entry',]

print(f'I want the items of {list1} and {list2}')
```

The output I want:

```
'I want the items of a and apple'
'I want the items of a and banana'
'I want the items of a and citrus'

etc.

'I want the items of a and apple'
'I want the items of b and apple'
'I want the items of c and apple'
```

So, I basically want all the possibilities of list 1 and list 2 in one string. In my example, this would result in 25 strings. I can't seem to get it right but I think I'm on the right track!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product

for (x, y) in product(list1, list2):
    print(f'I want the items of {x} and {y}')
```

**Output:**

```
I want the items of a and apple
I want the items of a and banana
I want the items of a and citrus
I want the items of a and denim
I want the items of a and entry
I want the items of b and apple
I want the items of b and banana
I want the items of b and citrus
I want the items of b and denim
I want the items of b and entry
I want the items of c and apple
I want the items of c and banana
I want the items of c and citrus
I want the items of c and denim
I want the items of c and entry
I want the items of d and apple
I want the items of d and banana
I want the items of d and citrus
I want the items of d and denim
I want the items of d and entry
I want the items of e and apple
I want the items of e and banana
I want the items of e and citrus
I want the items of e and denim
I want the items of e and entry
```

Comment: You are a god! Thanks Deadshot!